# track iis work process resets

Tags: iis, iis-6, worker-process

Is there any way to know if IIS resets the app pool/worker process, in IIS 6?

We're seeing funny results in our web application, and I think it has to do with sessions being cleared because the work precess is being recycled, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post should help guide you with IIS 6. If you are using ASP.Net then you can make the web.config changes suggested in the article.  Note that this technique does not work if the application pool process is killed, but IIS will write a message to the Event Log if it is killing the application pool.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2008/02/18/monitoring-application-pool-and-application-restarts.aspx